# jar files are different from different maven (same version)?

Tags: maven-2

The jar file generated from my local maven (2.0.8) is different from the jar file generated from the enterprise central build (maven 2.0.8). All the source code and pom files are the same, as well as the repository link. But when I ran a job using the jar from central build, here is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:122)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:918)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:899)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:358)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoader(XmlBeans.java:770)
    (deleted....)
    ... 15 more


Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:501)
    ... 17 more


Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeLoaderException: XML-BEANS compiled schema: Incompatible minor version - expecting up to 23, got 24 (schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.s4260D8D66C8BD97BA7A1A374DB7D9EB0.index) - code 3
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl$XsbReader.<init>(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:1522)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl.initFromHeader(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:260)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl.<init>(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:183)
    ... 21 more
```

But the job ran successfully using the jar file generated from my local maven.

Can you give me any suggestions that what I should look into in order to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i would suggest to update your Maven installation at least to Maven 2.0.11 (which is the newest for 2.0 line) but better to Maven 3...
I would check if you are using the same java compiler for both areas

Comment: Thanks. It was the problem of the java compiler version difference. However I used maven-compiler-plugin and I specified the source and target as 1.5. But on the central build machine, the JAVA_HOME points to java6. How should I change the settings of maven so that maven will use java 5 when JAVA_HOME points to java 6. Thanks.